# Orchard CMS Extension Manifest could not loaded

Tags: module, widget, orchardcms

I'm trying to make my own calendar widget  and module by following a tutorial on youtube and everything works fine until now. I got this kind of error in the  Orchard Dashboard

```
  "The extension 'BYUtv.CalendarWidget' manifest could not be loaded. It was ignored."
```

I'm using visual studio 2012 in the development and oddly the VS 2012 doesn't show me any error message at all. I'm using Orchard version 1.6.1.0. Can anyone tell me what seems to be the problem? Thanks

Comment: Have you added a resources manifest file? If so, what is the code in that? If not, how are you loading your styles/scripts?

Comment: I'm sorry I'm new to this, is the manifest you mean the txt. formatted file? I just run the project via VS 2012.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like there is something wrong with your `Module.txt`. Check that the file is valid, and check your file system permissions for that module.

If that fails, then from searching Orchard's code you should in that the error message is emitted from `Orchard.Environment.Extensions.Folders.ExtensionHarvester`. Put a breakpoint in the `AvailableExtensionsInFolder` method in that class and step through until you get an exception message.